# Feign recognized GET method as POST

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-feign

I have a service defined as follow

```
class Echo {
  private String message; // getters and setters omitted
}

@RequestMapping("/app")
interface Resource {
  @RequestMapping(method = GET)
  Echo echo(@ModelAttribute Echo msg);
}

@RestController
class ResourceImpl implements Resource {
  @Override
  Echo echo(Echo msg) { return msg; }
}
```

and his client on a different application

```
@FeignClient(name = "app", url = "http://localhost:8080")
interface Client extends Resource {}
```

However, when I call resource method

```
@Autowired
private Resource client;

@Test
public void test() {
  Echo echo = new Echo();
  echo.setMessage("hello");
  client.echo(echo);
}
```

I got a confusing error message

> feign.FeignException: status 405 reading ClientLocal#echo(Echo);
>   content: {"timestamp":1512686240485,"status":405,"error":"Method Not
>   Allowed","exception":"org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException","message":"Request
>   method 'POST' not supported","path":"/app"}

What I did wrong here?

Comment: Try updating to the most recent versions of Spring Cloud Feign and if that does not work, then log an issue on github.

Answer (score 4):

Found the same issue and for me the reason of POST with GET mixing by Feign is usage of Object as request param

was with same error as yours:

```
@GetMapping("/followers/{userId}/id")
Page<String> getFollowersIds(@PathVariable String userId, Pageable pageable);
```

added @RequstParam for 2 argument fixed it, like:

```
@GetMapping("/followers/{userId}/id")
Page<String> getFollowersIds(@PathVariable String userId, @RequestParam Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: Thanks for this! On my end, I had used Param instead of RequestParam causing the same issue. Resolving this worked.