# Feign recognise GET method as POST

Tags: spring, http, request, spring-cloud, feign

I have problem in my spring Cloud application, which is using consule for service discovery.

CartController calls method from VehicleController-

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/cart")
public class CartController {

   @Autowired
    VehicleServiceProxy vehicleServiceProxy;


    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET,value = "/test",produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<?> test() {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(vehicleServiceProxy.test(1L).getBody(), HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
    }

}
```

FeignClient

```
@FeignClient(name="vehicle")
public interface VehicleServiceProxy {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/vehicles/test", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> test(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long id);

}
```

VehicleController

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("vehicles")
public class VehicleController {

    @Autowired
    VehicleService vehicleService;


    @RequestMapping(value = "test", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> test(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(vehicleService.getById(id), HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
    }


}
```

I looked at some answers on internet and I am aware that the problem is that I have **@PathVariable** inside of get request and that for some Reason feign converts the GET request to POST request, also I found this answer: [Feign recognized GET method as POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47705024/feign-recognized-get-method-as-post) but the solution did not work for me,nor do I think that it is the right way to resolve this problem.

Stacktrace of error:

```
vehicle-service_1  | 2020-06-18 16:48:16.087  WARN 7 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported]
cart-service_1     | 2020-06-18 16:48:16.259 ERROR 11 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is feign.Fe
ignException$MethodNotAllowed: [405] during [GET] to [http://vehicle/vehicles/test] [VehicleServiceProxy#test(Long)]: [{"timestamp":"2020-06-18T16:48:16.108+0000","status":405,"error":"Method Not Allowed","message":"Request method 'POST' not supported","path":"/veh
icles/test"}]] with root cause
cart-service_1     |
cart-service_1     | feign.FeignException$MethodNotAllowed: [405] during [GET] to [http://vehicle/vehicles/test] [VehicleServiceProxy#test(Long)]: [{"timestamp":"2020-06-18T16:48:16.108+0000","status":405,"error":"Method Not Allowed","message":"Request method 'POST
' not supported","path":"/vehicles/test"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was missing /{id}, in RequestMapping(value = "test/{id}")

```
@RestController
    @RequestMapping("vehicles")
    public class VehicleController {

        @Autowired
        VehicleService vehicleService;


        @RequestMapping(value = "test", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        public ResponseEntity<?> test(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(vehicleService.getById(id), HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
        }


    }
```

Comment: you forgot to change value in in RequestMapping.it should be like:@RequestMapping(value = "test/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)